# Invalid path issue on Windows due to ":", "*" charcters in the route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, path, react-router

```
error: invalid path 'src/pages/vacancies/vacancy/:id/index.js'
```

React-router path requires (:) to indicate url params, :id in the case.
It's invalid for Windows not allowing to checkout on the branch I need

Is there any other option to bypass this issue so I can checkout seamlessly wherever I want to?
Changing (:) for (*) didn't help either.
It happens only on Windows (Mac/Linux - no problems with them)

Comment: I don't think it's a valid unix path either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have suspicions that you are using `Next.js`. And there, dynamic parameters are processed a little differently. Try using the `[id]` folder.

As a result, you should have the following project structure:

```sh
.
└── src
    └── pages
        └── vacancies
            └── vacancy
                └── [id]
                    └── index.js
```

Comment: Yes, worked but a new hell circle was initiated xD


`PageCreator: Found a client route, but the proper env was not set to enable this experimental feature. Please run again with GATSBY_EXPERIMENTAL_ROUTING_APIS=1 to enable.`